# PHP: Iterate through a list on page refresh

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a list of images that need to be shown in a certain order.

I'd like to iterate through these images via a page reload.

ie. `first load -> image 1, second load -> image 2, etc`

I'm doing this on laravel 5.1 by using sessions, but for some reason I keep getting the same list over and over again.

```
function show($id) {

    // .. snip
    if ( ! session()->has('images') ) {

        $list = Images::all();

        session()->put('images', $list);
    }

    $banners = session()->pull('images');
    $banner = $banners->shift();

    if (!$banners->isEmpty()) {
        session()->put('images', $banners);
    }

    dd($banner);
}
```

I keep coming up with the same banner here. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/facepalm`

I forgot I was using Lumen for this site and not Laravel. I just enabled Sessions as per [documentation](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/session).